# eclipse helios fails to find g++, gdb, $PATH, make

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse CDT but it fails to find any of the linux toolchain like make, g++, gdb. seems like it is failing to retrieve $PATH.Could you let me know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure g++/gdb are installed?

Does PATH really points to the right directories?

If everything seems ok, on Eclipse go to:

```
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Environment
```

At this point you should see the list of Environment variables eclipse is currently using. You could add PATH to that list by clicking and selecting it on the window displayed by the Select button (right below the Add button).

Comment: Yes, the toolchains and compiler are installed. Still I am having the problem